# Modifying BAQ to query with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, erp

I have created a dynamic query which can return a dataset from an external BAQ. I want the dyanmic query to only return the records which meet the parameters I have parsed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
// DynamnicQuery for BAQ
        Epicor.Mfg.Core.Session epiSession = default(Epicor.Mfg.Core.Session);
        epiSession = (Epicor.Mfg.Core.Session)POEntryForm.Session;
        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = new Epicor.Mfg.BO.DynamicQuery(epiSession.ConnectionPool);
        //Build Data Set
        QueryExecutionDataSet executionDS = new QueryExecutionDataSet();
        //Build parametors
        QueryExecutionDataSet parameters = new QueryExecutionDataSet();
        DataRow paramRow = parameters.ExecutionParameter.NewRow();
        paramRow["ParameterName"] = "POSuggestionsView.PartNum";
        paramRow["ParameterValue"] = "10050886";
        paramRow["ValueType"] = "nvarchar(50)";
        paramRow["IsEmpty"] = "False";
        paramRow["RowIdent"] = "";
        paramRow["RowMod"] = "";
        paramRow["DBRowIdent"] = new byte[0];
        parameters.ExecutionParameter.Rows.Add(paramRow);
        // Out variable which indicates if more results are available (likely for use with topNRecords)
        bool hasMoreRecords = false;
        //Executed named BAQ with parameter...
        DataSet results = dynamicQuery.ExecuteByIDParametrized("AD-999-SB_POSuggestion", parameters, "", 0, out hasMoreRecords);
        //Message Each Description....
        MessageBox.Show("Number of rows in Results = " + results.Tables["Results"].Rows.Count.ToString());
        foreach (DataRow item in results.Tables["Results"].Rows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Row Value = " + item["POSuggestionsView.PartNum"].ToString());
    }
```

The code I have created still returns all of the values from the table without restricting the returned rows to the ones which meet the condition of the parameter. Can anyone help me as to why this is happening please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Parameter in the BAQ.

Open the BAQ editor and navigate to the Phrase Build tab, select the table you want to add the parameter to.

Add a new criteria to the table in the section below, the filter type will be "Specified Parameter". Take note of the parameter name.

Save the BAQ.

Back in your customization modify the paramRow["ParameterName"] = the parameter name you created in the BAQ.